# How to update any value in '.properties' file programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android

In my app I have manually created one properties file ("MyConfig.properties") in "assets" ("src/main/assets") folder. This file has one entry i.e. **DeviceUuid= xyzabc** now I want to update this value to  **DeviceUuid= pqrstabc** and for that I have written below code---

```
public static void setProperty(String key, String value, Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("MyConfig.properties");
            // set the properties value
            properties.setProperty(key, value);

            // save properties to project root folder
            properties.store(output, null);

            output.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to WRITE Property "+key);
            Log.e(TAG, ""+ex);
        }
    }
```

but I'm always getting below exception--

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: MyConfig.properties (Read-only file system)
```

I did some RND on it and tried different available solutions on google but none of them worked for me.

I have written below code to read the value from the same properties file and it is working fine---

```
public static String getProperty(String key, Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            Properties properties = new Properties();;
            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("MyConfig.properties");
            properties.load(inputStream);
            return properties.getProperty(key);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to READ Property "+key);
            Log.e(TAG, ""+ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if I can provide more details for the same. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`new FileOutputStream("MyConfig.properties");` does not point to a valid location. You need to provide a `File` object that points to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html), or perhaps [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: You are right. I did some RND on 'How to get .properties file path from the assets folder?' but none from the available solution helped me. Thank you.